# How to return nothing from an integer function in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
int test(int a){
    if (a > 10){
        return a;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Error!";
        return nothing;
    }
}
int main(){
    std::cout << test(9);
    return 0;
}
```

What I want is that The integer function `test(int a)`, return `a` if `a > 10`, otherwise return `Error!`. but since this is an integer function, it must return an integer value, but I want that it print Error and return nothing. Is there a way for do this? (Also note that I don't want to use a void function)

Comment: There is no such thing as `nothing` in C++. Either change the return type to `void` or return something like `0` or whatever `int` value you choose/want. One alternative is to use exceptions and `throw`. Also, see [In a non-void function I want to return nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64517100/in-a-non-void-function-i-want-to-return-nothing)

Comment: You can't return nothing. Perhaps you should return 0 or a negative number to indicate there was an error. Of course you'd have to change the code where you call it to handle that error as well. In general I wouldn't have any output in the function and instead have the caller decide whether to print the value or "Error!".

Comment: Consider introducing [exceptions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception).

Comment: @amin have a look at `std::optional`

Comment: Why not just make the function returning a boolean indicating succcess/failure and maybe  an out-parameter (or inout-parameter). This has been done for ages. Most io-function work like this. It very readable and self-explaning.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
#include <stdexcept>

int test(int a){
    if (a > 10){
        return a;
    }
        else{
            throw std::invalid_argument( "a is smaller or eq than 10" );
    
        }

}
```

Comment: This is not valid C++. You missed the if branch.

Comment: A good answer should not just provide code (especially if it's just a few lines without context), but explain why and how it solves the problem at hand. OP wanted to _"print Error and return nothing"_ - that's not what your code does. You should at least  explain, why you would prefer exceptions.

Comment: @churill.. if you trow something that's it.
You cannot return after you throw. try it and u will see your code would not even compile.

Comment: @moldovean Well ... that's my point. OP want's to "return nothing" (which is possible with `std::optional`), but you suggest exceptions. This decision should be explained, I think.

Comment: " try it and u will see your code would not even compile" of course it would comile

Comment: @Churill ... mmm.. yes, one could theoretically solve this thing through an optional. indeed. That would also be a valid answer.  Optional is a lil bit more advanced. because something else would have to read it and evaluate it. this lines however, `std::cout << "Error!";
        return nothing;' made me think Amin wanted a quick solution to terminating a program with an error